# How to avoid duplicate database records but in regard to a specific user?

Tags: laravel

For example:
User with an id '1135' wants to create a new recipe under 'Banana split.'
However, he already has a recipe under that name. So, we would like to deny that entry because it's a duplicate for this user.

Recipes for user 1135:

```
[id] [name]  
[4] Banana split  
[57] Fire Tacos  
[210] Chili N' Beans
```

Intuitively, we would use validation like follows:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|unique:recipes, name'
]);
```

However, the name 'Banana split' should be allowed for other users, but only once.
So the goal is to make the recipe name unique to the recipes table (column: name) with regard to the user_id.

Comment: Check out the documentation for the Unique rule: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique, it notes ways to ignore a given ID (i.e. whatever references the current User), and other ways to handle this scenario. You _shouldn't_ need a custom validator.

Comment: I want to move the logic away from the controller so it doesn't hurt to put the validation under the rules() method of the request. Interestingly, ignoring the given id is the opposite of what I'm trying to do. So, in that case, we would like to ignore all the other ids. So, I reckon if the database has 3000 users, we wouldn't want to ignore 3000 users. Instead, we take this user's recipes and make a Rule::unique chained with where-> clause. Again I'm not sure, but something similar, yet quite the opposite of ignoring the ID

Comment: You wouldn't be ignoring all other ids per-se, you'd be setting the unique rule to check for a combination of `name` and `user_id`, so that each User can create a recipe with the same name. The documentation shows how to do that with `where()` clauses.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I reckon ```->ignore``` will only exclude this user from the check, but I actually want JUST this user in the check. I solved it. Answer below. Please comment there if you have a better way.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I was saying *"you'd be setting the unique rule to check for a combination of `name` and `user_id`"*; not sure where you saw `->ignore` or anything (or well, the documentation I guess, but wrong section). Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this validation:

```
Rule::unique('recipes', 'name')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
})
```

translation:

> the name field must be unique in recipes table, for results that match this user's id.